# How do I fix 'stringing' while creating a plane from an outer loop (of vertices)

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

### Background information

I am trying to create a 3d relief model of Switzerland, I have generated an STL file and cut out the Switzerland shape for later smoothing. This has resulted in my model being hollow, which I am trying to solve by selecting the outer loop of vertices and pressing F.

### Issue

The result is shown in the image below, a large part of the 'plane/ngon' seems to be correct, however certain parts are missing and 'stringing'. I am wondering what could possibly cause this issue and how I could solve it.
[image: Result of my model]

Comment: Try using `Grid Fill` instead of `F`